# Can charts or tables be exported in different formats?

Tags: javascript, charts, datatables

Has [Google library for charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/) a feature which able user export data as csv, excel, pdf or png?
I would like something like [datatables library](https://datatables.net/) does, giving this options automatically by buttons.
Considering this propose, would better use the google library or datatable library? 
In my project I'm already using [angular-material library](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/), in some pages will containing both charts and datatabels, and it will be filled by [angular 1](https://angularjs.org/) request response.

Comment: use the [`getImageURI`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/printing) method to get chart png

Answer (score 1):

from the docs it seems you can export as HTML or CSV. https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/toolbar

Comment: I do not found it, unfortunately its not all options datatables library has , but it's can help. Thanks man